# ClassLoader.getResource keeps returning null for existing resource

Tags: java, database, file, url, path

I am trying to include a local database file in my Runnable Jar. The application is based on an exisiting open source project, in wich they had the file in the package together with the Class. Now I am moving the database file to a 'res' map I created in the root project folder. Editing the code to find the new path to the database file didn't work. This is the piece of code:

```
 private static String defaultDBFileLocation() {
        final URL geoDBFileURL = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("res/GeoIP.dat");
//        final URL geoDBFileURL = GeoIPServiceImpl.class.getResource("GeoIP.dat");
        if (geoDBFileURL == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            final URI geoDBFileURI = geoDBFileURL.toURI();
            if (!geoDBFileURI.getScheme().equals("file")) {
                // class file loaded not from plain directory on filesystem, e.g. from jar, network, etc.
                return null;
            }
            final File geoDBFile = new File(geoDBFileURI);
            return geoDBFile.getPath();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The commmented line is the way the original creators used to get the file. The line above it is my new way. This method keeps returning null at this line:

```
if (geoDBFileURL == null)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Is your class loaded by the system classloader?

Comment: How do I know if it is?

Comment: `System.out.println(YourClass.class.getClassLoader() == ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() ? "Loaded by system classloader" : "Loaded by another classloader");`, but why not just use YourClass.class.getClassLoader() to start with if that's the intention?

Comment: It is loaded by the system classloader. But wouldnt that suggestion require me to have the file next to the class? Because for some reason, the file doesn't get included in the jar that way

Comment: `YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("res/GeoIP.dat")` (for ClassLoader.getResource, path is relative to jar) or `YourClass.class.getResource("/res/GeoIP.dat")` (for Class.getResource, path is relative to the class unless it starts with /) should work. But if this isn't what's causing the problem, this won't fix it, of course.

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but there is a file called `GeoIP.dat` in a folder called `res` in your JAR file, right?

Comment: It should be, when I create a JAR. But I can't even get it to work from Eclipse right now

Comment: In Eclipse: is there a file called `GeoIP.dat` in a "package" called `res`? (Eclipse should show it as a package even though it doesn't have Java files, IIRC)

Comment: It's in a source folder yes. Like this rootfolder/res/GeoIP.dat It doesnt really show up as a package

Comment: Where are your java files? Something like `src/yourpackage/YourClass.java`?

Comment: Then the resource `res/GeoIP.dat` must be found at `src/res/GeoIP.dat`.

Comment: That works, but it still somehow isn't included in the JAR file when I export it.

Comment: Then it sounds like the question you are asking isn't the one that needs to be solved. What you need to know is "How do I make eclipse include this file in my JAR?"

Comment: Already tried that, the only answers I got were some form of: Include it in your build path. But since it is located in the src folder, it is already included. So I just tried it this way

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader%28%29)) instead of the system class loader, which is "the default delegation parent for new ClassLoader instances, and is typically the class loader used to start the application" ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader%28%29)).